# How to run mutiple container with docker?

Tags: docker, docker-compose

I want to run laravel at docker, so I create a docker-compose.yml like following:

```
version: '3'
services:
  web:
    image: my-laravel-image
    ports:
        - 3021:8000
    volumes:
        - ./laravel-app:/app
```

**my-laravel-image** is create by:

```
FROM php:7
RUN apt-get update -y && apt-get install -y libmcrypt-dev openssl
RUN docker-php-ext-install pdo mcrypt mbstring
RUN curl -sS https://getcomposer.org/installer | php -- --install-dir=/usr/local/bin --filename=composer
WORKDIR /app
COPY . /app

CMD php artisan serve --host=0.0.0.0 --port=8000
EXPOSE 8000
```

When I run **docker-compose up --force-recreate -d** then access **127.0.0.1:3021** at browser, it works successfully.

Now I want to use **php** and **composer** offical image to build two container and connect each other, how to do it?

Following is what I tried:

```
version: '3'

services:
    php:
        image: php:7-fpm
        ports: 
          - "3021:8000"
        volumes:
            - ./laravel-app:/app
    composer:
        image: composer:latest
        volumes:
            - ./laravel-app:/app
        working_dir: /app
        command: ["install","php artisan serve --host=0.0.0.0"]
        depends_on:
            - php
```

When I run **docker-compose up --force-recreate -d** and **docker-compose log**, it shows following error:

```
Invalid argument php artisan serve --host=0.0.0.0. Use "composer require php artisan serve --host=0.0.0.0" instead to add packages to your composer.json.
```

How to fix it?

Answer (score 1):

I think the problem is this, you are trying to execute this command:

```
$ install php artisan serve --host=0.0.0.0
```

When they should be two command like this:

```
$ composer install & php artisan serve --host=0.0.0.0
```

regards.

Comment: Hello, I change my code into command: install & php artisan serve --host=0.0.0.0, but still not working.

Comment: docker-compose shows this error now:
The "--host" option does not exist.

Comment: Hi, if you type composer --help you will see that the option --host does not exists. i tried with command: "composer require & php artisan serve" and works.

Comment: composer supposes that exists a composer.json.

Comment: Hello, if I tried command: "composer require & php artisan serve", docker-compose logs won't show anything about composer container, and 127.0.0.1:3021 still not showing anything either.

Comment: the port 3021 you are using it in the php service. i do not know if the port 8000 is correct on this image, i would think would be the port 80. Check it out  the documentation [link]https://hub.docker.com/_/php/[/link]